# What is the difference between Anglia and England?

Tags: differences, british-english

What is the difference between [Anglia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglia_(disambiguation)) and [England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/England)? When it's used.

---

Some examples of modern usages:

- probably coincident, but Anglia in Polish language is England,
- there are regions called [East Anglia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Anglia), [Mid Anglia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_Anglia) and [West Anglia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Anglia),
- there are schools such as [Anglia Ruskin University](http://www.anglia.ac.uk/) in Cambridge, [The College of West Anglia](http://www.cwa.ac.uk/), [Anglia Ruskin Students' Union](http://www.angliastudent.com/),
- [Anglian Water](http://www.anglianwater.co.uk/) in the UK, Anglian Bus,
- [Greater Anglia](https://www.greateranglia.co.uk/) trains and [Anglia Railways](http://www.angliarailways.co.uk/),
- and similar

Comment: I don't know about my UK-based friends here on ELU, but here in the US, I've literally never heard anyone say or use "*Anglia*". That said, [Wikipedia suggests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglia) it is sometimes used for "*A name for the **eastern part of England**, including East Anglia, Mid Anglia and West Anglia*".

Comment: It's really only used for 'East-Anglia', which consists of three counties south of 'The Wash'. I doubt if anyone uses 'Mid-Anglia' any more and definitely not 'West-Anglia'. It is also the name of a Ford model manufactured from 1940(ish) to the late 1960's - The Ford Anglia.

Comment: Do you see a difference between when it's used and when it's not used? In other words, when a thing is not used one would suppose there can be no problem with it. E.g., if you don't use a knife you won't cut yourself with it.

Comment: kenorb: You keep adding bullets to your question, but Marv has covered them all already. As he said, the word for "England" in Latin was "Anglia", which is where and when Polish imported it (ie a long time ago), and the other three items are all related to his point that the eastern part of the island is sometimes (infrequently) called "Anglia" (that's where the university is, that's what the rail franchise covers, and that what it says on some old signs in "East Anglia"). But heed him: "*Anglia*"  is almost unused is modern English, and in any case never refers to the whole island or nation.

Comment: I've added few examples to show modern usages of it. I'm seeing Anglia word quite often in London especially on some advert banners, so I won't agree this word is unused.

Comment: Well, you came here to ask, and you got your answer. It's yours to do with what you want (but fortunately the *next* guy who's bamboozled by fantastic adverts will find Marv's answer to set him straight).

Comment: It's one of those words whose primary sense is dead (it formerly referred to the realm of the Angles, but who knows where the Angles are these days) but persists in a lot of derivatives and compounds. It's common to give a business or organisation an archaic, poetic, or vague name that doesn't exactly refer to any modern entity - names like Mercia, Wessex, Hallam(shire), Middlesex, Westmoreland, Caledonia, Alba, Welsh Marches, etc, are commonly used for businesses and organisations in the UK despite these entities not keeping to specific boundaries or borders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anglia is the Medieval (Latin) name for England and has never been used in my earshot to refer to the country of England (I am English). If it were used now it would imply that the subject of the usage was ancient England.

There is still an area of England known as "East Anglia" in common usage, but there is no common usage of North, West or South Anglia (though I imagine these regions may have local usage of these terms).